# CSS Circle without using background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a circle using only css. I've done this using the below:

```
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
```

I've created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rg991koa/11/

I'm basically trying to `onClick` add an image but my `background-image` isn't displaying within the circle and I think this is due to me using `background` colour on my element.

Comment: *"images changes from white to black."* Where is the image?

Comment: if it's only going from black to white, why not use a background color?

Comment: They're just icons. I have a white icon and a black icon, `onClick` I toggle a class that adds either a black or white icon. But the CSS circle above having background on it isn't allowing me to add an image

Comment: use the onclick to toggle a class which contains the background image  as css?

Comment: Wow, I really don't understand clearly what you want, sorry :(

Comment: *"But the CSS circle above having background on it isn't allowing me to add an image"* Why you want both image and background color?

Comment: @DevJuniorThe50421st: The image you are trying to show as a background is too huge for a 45px box. Add this to your css -- `background-size: 45px;`. Check this -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rg991koa/19/

Comment: @ByScripts Sorry dude! I may of explained that a bit difficult. I've updated the question and my jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rg991koa/17/ this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `background-image` to `background`

```
.myNewClass {
  background: url(http://static4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131121214007/destinypedia/images/7/71/Information_Icon.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rg991koa/21/